# Changing user id from string to int (aspnet core identity)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, userid

I am just trying to build a simple blog app on blazor server app. I only included Login, Register and Logout using Identity scaffolder. I am trying to convert user id from string to int. Followed MS documentation and here is what I have done so far:

[I created these 2 classes and replaced all the IdentityUser and IdentityRole classes with these in my project like login, program.cs and register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdJeW.png)

[Here is the DBContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlbdV.png)

[This is program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWYnQ.png)

[This error shows up when I run the solution. Any idea on how to resolve this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9ZSf.png)

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the question. I updated it now

Comment: Did you remove your website cookies? Did you update the database after switching from guid to int (`dotnet ef database update`)? Did you remove the existing user records from the database?

Comment: yes I did that. I think it has something to do with user store class. I didnt change that

Comment: FindByIdAsync in user store still has string type user id. I guess thats what causing this. Any Idea how to change it. Examples I found were from older version of Identity which dont work now

Comment: Maybe you can search the database with [efcore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/) rather than [FindByIdAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.findbyidasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0).